# ImportError: cannot import name 'timedelta

Tags: python

I am getting the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'timedelta'.`

from this line in my code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
```

I just  installed pandas using `pip install pandas` and also `conda install -f pandas`

I dont get any error when I write `import pandas`. When I write `which python`  I get `/Users/zpu/miniconda3/bin/python`
When I want to debug the first line is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
```

Comment: Who is importing `timedelta` where? Show a complete error with complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Timedelta does not come from datetime module? If you shown your code, we could know better.

Comment: Show the code and copy paste the traceback, better than images...

Comment: image and the code are added to the post.. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your script name is `datetime.py`. If so, choose another name that doesn't clash with the standard library.

Comment: Images of text are generally not recommended on SO. Giant images of text are _really_ annoying... Please see [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/4014959). Sure, your screenshots aren't of code, per se, but there's still no benefit of posting them as images rather than as searchable text & they waste disk space and bandwidth. And they're annoying for people browsing on mobile devices. Etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting rid of those screenshots!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As DeepSpace said, you must not name your script "datetime.py", since in that case, `from datetime import timedelta` would try to import a function/class called "timedelta" **from your script**, not the standard library.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. In your opinion, is my list of pythons in Preferences OK, or I should remove python2.6?

Comment: You usually don't need python 2.6, since it is really old and I know no programs that work in python 2.6 but not 2.7.